# Changing file name

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following code snippet

```
public static string AppendDateTimeToFileName(this string fileName)
{
   return string.Concat(
      Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
      DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"),
      Path.GetExtension(fileName));
}
```

This basically puts a date time stamp on any file that is being uploaded by the users. Now this works great is the file name is something like

- MyFile.png
- AnotherFile.png

Now I'm trying to change this method so if the file name is something like

- MyFile - Copy(1).png
- AnotherFile - Copy(1).png

I want the file name to become

- MyFile-Copy-120170303131815555.png
- AnotherFile-Copy-120170303131815555.png

If there an easy soltuion for this with `regex` or similar or do I have to re-write the method again and check each of those values one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return string.Concat(
      Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), @" - Copy\s*\(\d+\)", "-Copy-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase),
      DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"),
      Path.GetExtension(fileName));
```

This matches any number of digits and is a global replace.

Comment: Thanks  for this, how would I accomodate for a file name **MyFile - copy(1).png**

Comment: `MyFile-Copy-20170303140526319.png` would be the result

Comment: If the **Copy** is in lower case will the regex still match?

Comment: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` means `Copy` can be in any case/mixture of case.

Comment: Thanks once again, I appreciate your help

Comment: I've just tried your code and it does not change the filename :/ this is what I get back `resultFileName = "Untitled - Copy (2)20170303142803439.png"` when I set a breakpoint

Comment: Because thats a different pattern, there is a space between `copy` and `(` unlike your original examples.  I have updated the answer to allow no space or any number of spaces between them.

Comment: Oops my apologies

Comment: `@"\s*-\s*Copy\s*\(\d+\)"` of course to allow for optional spaces around the `-`

Comment: Thank you, I better include that in just in case the requirement arises in the near future